# Detect mousedown and touchstart pageX on another function

Tags: javascript, settimeout, touch-event, jquery-events, touchstart

I have an event to detect mouse or touch and send this event to another function using setTimeout.

I have no problem detecting mouse or touch event, what I can not do is send touch event to the function.

```
$(divst + ' #sortable1').on('touchstart mousedown',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function(){
                    StarTrans(e); // <- sending event
        },200);
});
function StarTrans(e){
    if(e.pageX==='undefined'){ // this does not work
        $(dtarget).offset({left:e.changedTouches[0].pageX-33,top:e.changedTouches[0].pageY-58});
        $('#titring').html(e.changedTouches[0].pageX + ',' + e.changedTouches[0].pageY);
    }else{ // this works
        $(dtarget).offset({left:e.pageX-33,top:e.pageY-58});
        $('#titring').html(e.pageX + ',' + e.pageY);
    }
}
```

mousedown works as expected, touchstart returns 'undefined'.

I tried these events to get pageX

- e.changedTouches[0].pageX
- e.targetTouches[0].pageX
- e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX
- e.touches[0].pageX
- e.pageX

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,
`if(e.pageX==='undefined'){` it's not correct. Better `if (typeof e.pageX == 'undefined') {` if you need that condition, more better `if (e.type == 'touchstart') {`.